# Консоль java нужно считать числа из строки чисел

Tags: java

Входные данные: 5 9 -5 7
Именно четыре числа и я не знаю как сделать это с помощью Scanner
Между числами всегда есть один пробел, а числа могут быть 1 < X < 10000

Comment: `Scanner.nextInt`.

Comment: Где строка? В памяти? Во входном потоке? В файле?

Comment: Сказано в вопросе, что строка в консоли

Comment: Тогда это простая задача. Добавьте в вопрос код вашей попытки читать числа из консоли. Разберёмся.

Comment: Scanner.nextInt берет только первое число, остальные игнорирует

Comment: Код в вопрос. Без кода я могу только гадать. Спасибо.

Comment: Вот код: 
'import java.util.Scanner;
public class New {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  int N = in.nextInt();
  System.out.print(N);
 }
}' и при входных данных: 3 4 5 6 выдает только 3

Comment: Один вызов - одно целое число. Вызывайте его несколько раз, что получить несколько значений.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы считать каждое последующее число, которое записано через пробел, нужно вызвать Scanner.nextInt() столько раз, сколько у вас чисел. (сам до этого почему то не додумался я)

Comment: Держите по плюсику за вопрос и за ответ. :)

Comment: Благодарю вас покорно)